# Why is Blend and Visual studio 12 throwing and exception?

Tags: c#, exception, blend

Hi I'm using some UserControls with empty logic in the constructor and they are throwing an exception. I don't get whats happening. All my user controls worked before the reléase candidate, in the developer preview, but after som adjustments to work on the RC the user controls refuse to be shown. The code runs perfectly but I cannot design properly.

```
 {
        this.InitializeComponent();
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your C# code. Look at the innermost exception: `XAML parsing failed.` This means you've most likely put something wrong (or broken) into your XAML file (the one belonging to the `TouristAttractionsListControl`). It's also possible, there's simply some change breaking this for you. Did you check the release notes? You could also try to recreate your control (XAML part only) and then compare the generated X(A)ML.

Comment: Hi, When I just créate a new user control from the menú, and then I add it to a Page, or another UserControl, it also throws an exception.

Comment: This sounds very odd, even with a new project (not reusing anything)?

Comment: With new projects it Works fine, but with the one I created with the DeveloperPreview crashes

Comment: So something changed. Exclude parts of the XAML with a comment to try to determine what causes it.